# Implement RSA_public_decrypt, or encryption verification, kernel mode

Tags: encryption, rsa, kernel-mode

I want to check whether a string is encrypted by RSA algorithm or not. This encryption checker must implemented in Kernel mode and worse than that it has to write in Win XP. I investigate OpenSSL and especially its RSA_public_decrypt but this function solely work in user mode and unfortunately I haven't saw the code. I supposed to verify a text with the given public key and signature. I  don't want to implement it by scratch since I have to manipulate with multiply big numbers.

Any bit advice will be noticeable
Sincerely yours

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about cryptographic analysis, and probably belongs on crypto.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to check whether a string is encrypted by RSA algorithm or not...

Well, once its encrypted it should be indistinguishable from random data. That's known as the PRP-notion of security. So you should not be able to tell if its random, encrypted under AES, encrypted under RSA, etc.

I think the only thing you can say about the data is "its not encrypted" *if* the message is not random data.